# Sortable jQueryUI Table Rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I have a table which displays parent-child relationship. I have made the table sortable using jQueryUI.

However, I want to restrict drag/drop of rows to within their parent.

So, for example, the child items - "Manual Items" and "Rec" - should only be sortable with their parent i.e. within "Positions" and should be restricted from moving to another parent.

Is this possible? I have tried adding *containment: "parent"* but no change.

```js
var currentID = 0;
$("#sortable").sortable({
    start: function (event, ui) {
        //debugger;
        currentID = $(ui.item).index();
        //console.log($(ui.item).index());
    },
    cancel: ".ui-state-disabled",
    update: function (event, ui) {
        //debugger;
        //console.log($(ui.item).data('id'));
        var newID = $(ui.item).index();
        alert('Current: ' + currentID.toString());
        alert('New: ' + newID.toString());
    }
});
$(".sortable").draggable({
    containment: "parent"
});

var viewModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;
   
    self.tasks = ko.observableArray([
    {TaskID: 1, TaskName: "ManualItems", Parent: 3},
    {TaskID: 2, TaskName: "Trades", Parent: null},
    {TaskID: 3, TaskName: "Positions", Parent: null},
    {TaskID: 4, TaskName: "Rec", Parent: 3},
    {TaskID: 5, TaskName: "Cash", Parent: null},
    {TaskID: 6, TaskName: "ReportA", Parent: 5},
    {TaskID: 7, TaskName: "FileIn", Parent: 2},
    {TaskID: 8, TaskName: "ReportB", Parent: 5}
    ]); 
    
  self.getChildren = function(row) {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.tasks(), function(item) {
      return item.Parent === row.TaskID
    });
  }

  self.filteredtasks = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.tasks(), function(item) {
      return !item.Parent;
    });
  }, this);    
   
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Parent ID</th>
                <th>Parent Task</th>
                <th>Task ID</th>
                <th>Task name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="sortable">
            <!-- ko foreach: filteredtasks -->
            <tr class="ui-state-default ui-state-disabled">
                <td class="ui-state-default" data-bind="text: TaskID"></td>
                <td class="ui-state-default" data-bind="text: TaskName"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <!-- ko foreach: $root.getChildren($data) -->
            <tr class="ui-state-default">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td data-bind="text: TaskID"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: TaskName"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Position"></td>
            </tr>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fvyw5yfv/

Answer (score 0):

I resolved something similar using a data-parentid="parentid" attribut on each row, and then in sortable stop function i just grab that data and check if the dropped have the correct id of current table, it should be something similar to :

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    start: function (event, ui) {
        //debugger;
        currentID = $(ui.item).index();
        //console.log($(ui.item).index());
    },
    cancel: ".ui-state-disabled",
    update: function (event, ui) {
        //debugger;
        //console.log($(ui.item).data('id'));
        var newID = $(ui.item).index();
        alert('Current: ' + currentID.toString());
        alert('New: ' + newID.toString());
    },stop: function(event, ui){
        if(ui.item.attr("data-parent") == 2){
        alert('wrong parent');
      }
    }
});
```

This is a test : http://jsfiddle.net/Kanzari/fvyw5yfv/7/

Hope it help,